# Centralizer of Maximal Toral Subalgebra of $L$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to understand the proof of the following result from Humphreys Lie Algebra book:

> Let $L$ be a semisimple complex Lie Algebra.Let $H$ be Maximal toral subalgebra of $H$,Let $C_L(H)$ denote the centralizer of $H$ in $L$.Show that $C_L(H)=H$.

The proof given in Humphreys book on page $36$ does not seem 'natural' to me,and i am having hard time with the steps of proof.I think i understand the proof but if someone will ask me to reproduce the proof i dont think i will to able to do so. Can someone give me a better reference or outline a "natural' proof or explain me the Humphreys proof properly.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what feels unnatural about the proof?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Honestly speaking,i dont see why any of the steps given in book are natural.obviously $H \subset C_L(H)$,so we just need to prove the reverse inequality.In the book,there are $7$ steps,could you please explain me the strategy of proving the reverse inequality?Thanks.

Comment: I think the proof may feel more natural if you do the steps backwards. The general idea is that if some element in the centralizer was not in $H$, then one could enlarge $H$ by this element to get a larger toral subalgebra unless this added element was nilpotent. Then to rule out the possibility of a nilpotent element, one uses how these behave relative to the Killing form and that this form should stay nondegenerate when restricted to $H$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft By seeing the proof bit carefully it seems that for proving the result its enough to prove that $C_L(H)$ is abelian.So ideas for proving this?Thanks

Comment: Well, that is what several of the points in Humphreys' proof do.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I mean what is the idea of those several steps?sorry for silly questions

Comment: The idea is to first prove that $C$ is nilpotent and then use that this means that if it is not abelian then there is some non-zero element which is in both the derived subalgebra and in the center. This element will then be nilpotent due to previous parts, but this implies that it annihilates everything when we apply the Killing form with it, contradicting nondegeneracy of the form.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think i understand the idea now,thanks a lot!